# How can we use .htaccess for windows server using php?

Tags: php, windows, .htaccess

I want to implement .htaccess for URL rewrite. I am using windows server.

I know there are two solutions:

1. using webconfig
2. using Helicon

I dont know how to write .htaccess code in webconfig file and I dont want to use Helicon because this is paid.

The code I want to implement in the webconfig file is :

```
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
    RewriteEngine on

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-d
    RewriteCond %{Request_Filenam}e !-f

    RewriteRule ^privacy  privacy.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^dating-articles dating-articles.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9A-Za-z_\-~',]+)    article_detail.html?article_link=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?page_slug=$1  [NC]

    </IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to look at how IIS configuration works.  It's very different from Apache

Comment: not sure what "windows server" means exactly, but I assume it is not apache (IIS maybe)? Then the question is - can't you just switch to apache (xamp, wamp, uniform server)? Because by default IIS does not support .htaccess and if you want apache compatible approach you'd need to purchase 3rd party module

Comment: "webconfig file" implies IIS I think.

Comment: btw: your .htaccess is incorrect. `RewriteEngine on` should be in `<ifModule>` block, not outside otherwise you get error 500 if there's none (on apache of course :)

Comment: iis has the rewrite module: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: can you tell me how can we write the code in the webconfig file to use php code in the html file?

Answer (score -1):

Windows 2012 and 2008 both have url rewrites. Just open your site in the information manager and in the center plane, hit the url rewrite to open it.
just add this in the inbound window.

```
RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-d
RewriteCond %{Request_Filenam}e !-f
RewriteRule ^privacy  privacy.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^dating-articles dating-articles.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9A-Za-z_\-~',]+)    article_detail.html?     article_link=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?page_slug=$1  [NC]
```